# Choppy received voice data over UDP

Tags: python, sockets, udp, voip

I'm trying to send voice data over a UDP socket, however the received voice data by the client is choppy.

Currently, I'm running `server.py` and `client.py` on the same machine. Perhaps this might be the problem? Another possibility is that short packets of voice data is being sent, and then it's played fast enough that it ends for a short moment. It might also be a hardware issue (I'm currently using a 2015 Macbook Pro).

I've implemented this program in TCP, and it works flawlessly. However, the main purpose of this program is to handle larger amounts of clients.

I'm going to try running these scripts on different machines to see if it works. The desired outcome is to play the received voice data in a smooth manner, rather than have the audio be played in a choppy form.

**server.py**

```
import socket
import pyaudio
import threading
from os import system

system('clear')

# Socket
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 6000
buffer = 2048
clients = []

# Audio
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
chunk = int(1024 * 4)


def client_listener():
    while True:
        data, address = host_socket.recvfrom(buffer)
        if address not in clients:
            print(f'New client: {address[0]}:{address[1]}')
            clients.append(address)
            print(clients)


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as host_socket:
    try:
        host_socket.bind((host, port))
        print(f'Server hosted at {host}:{port}\n')

        print('Starting listener thread...')
        listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_listener)
        listener_thread.daemon = True
        listener_thread.start()
        print('Listener thread started!')

        print('Initiating microphone...')
        stream = audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                            channels=1,
                            rate=44100,
                            input=True,
                            frames_per_buffer=chunk)

        print('Recording!')
        while True:
            voice_data = stream.read(chunk, exception_on_overflow=False)
            for client in clients:
                host_socket.sendto(voice_data, client)
    except socket.error as error:
        print(str(error))
        stream.close()
        host_socket.close()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        stream.close()
        host_socket.close()
    finally:
        stream.close()
        host_socket.close()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket
import pyaudio
from os import system

# Socket
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 6000

system('clear')

# Audio
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
chunk = int(1024 * 4)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as client_socket:
    try:
        client_socket.sendto(' '.encode('utf-8'), (host, port))

        stream = audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                            channels=1,
                            rate=44100,
                            output=True,
                            frames_per_buffer=chunk)

        while True:
            voice_data = client_socket.recv(chunk)
            print(voice_data)
            stream.write(voice_data)
    except socket.error as error:
        print(str(error))
        stream.close()
        client_socket.close()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        stream.close()
        client_socket.close()
    finally:
        stream.close()
        client_socket.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

From a networking point of view, I can see why TCP worked flawlessly over UDP.
Transmission Control Protocol is an error correcting protocol - aka lossless -  and tracks what is being sent to determine errors. If the data sent is not complete for what ever reason, it asks to resend it.
User Datagram Protocol is not error correcting and more streaming like - one after the other. 
I don't know python, but I would suggest that if you create your own error correction method, then it would get the same effect as TCP if your going to use UDP. Something like a MD5 check, something that the receiver will know that "this packet of information is complete."

Comment: The stuttering appears to be a constant stutter. To best describe it, the audio will cut out every half a second for a short moment. Does this have to do with packet loss and error control? I imagine if it was packet loss, the stuttering would NOT be constant and would vary.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of jitter buffer - take a look at some open source SIP/RTP applications as this function might be quite complicated in practice, handling also packet reordering, coupled with some kind of PLC to compensate for packet loss and with adaptive delay depending on actual network jitter. If you have more than one device there would be also hard to avoid clock skew.

I'm also not entirely sure if python is good choice for server with large number of clients. I guess python + pjsip is more typical.